# "Do what you can": Is 做可做的 natural?

Tags: translation, phrase, nuance

The title pretty much says it all. It makes sense to me, but Google gives "do it" when I plug the Chinese phrase into it. If 做可做的 sounds awkward or stilted, what would be a better way to express it?

Comment: see jukuu for "do what you can":尽力做你所能做的事情,etc. 做可做的 seems unintelligible

Comment: Commonly pointed out in Chinese language learning materials (e.g. [here](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Comparing_%22hui%22_%22neng%22_%22keyi%22) is a three way distinction between 可, 能, and 会. See which word works most appropriate for what you are trying to express.

Comment: does your 做可做的 come from a machine translated statement? if so, please don't trust it and find original statement instead. Possible translations: try your best; show your best experiences; do thing supposed to be allowed.  可 can be understood as : able to do, suggest to do, allowed to do.

Comment: Hi again, @DanielYeung! The Chinese was actually my (very elementary) attempt to translate the English myself.

Comment: Generally 做你能做的 is better than 做你可做的,  where, 能做的 (有能力 able to) means that you can do it, while 可做的 (可以做/有能力/胜任  或 允许做) means that you are allowed to do it. Without context, audience cannot know it means 能/胜任/可以 or 允许, so that use 做你能做的 to avoid confusion。in most scenarios, 能 = able to, 可 = allowed (e.g. has a certificate, granted).

Comment: So what I wrote is more like "do what you may," or "do what is allowed," rather than "do what you can" or "do what is possible"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

做你能做的

or

做你可做的 sometimes means 'Do what you allowed'

and

做你力所能及的, Do what you are abled to

Answer (score 0):

做(v): to do

可做的(adj): doable (able to do/ allowed to do)

The phrase '**做可做的**' literally mean '**do the doable**' with the object 事/事情 omitted. It would be more natural and unambiguous to have the object intact.

For example:

- 做事- do thing
- 做**可做的**事- do the **doable** thing

(*thing that you are able to do/ thing that you are allowed to do*)

To sound more natural, you should use the compound word 可以 instead of the single character 可 and write: "做可以做的事"

Answer (score 0):

There is a phrase "盡力而為" which means "do your best".